# Do Tuvok and Neelix have Tuvix's memories?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Voyager episode Tuvix, Tuvix has Neelix's and Tuvok's memories. After Janeway murders Tuvix and separates Tuvok and Neelix at the end of the episode do they possess Tuvix's memories?

Comment: "Murders" is debatable. That was, after all, the major philosophical debate of the episode.

Comment: @Omegacron: Not really.  Tuvix existed as his own individual.  He lived, and given no outside interference, would have continued to do so.  Janeway knowingly took actions which resulted in him no longer being alive.  As long as you don't debate the personhood and individuality of Tuvix, it's extremely straightforward.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the personhood of Tuvix - his right to live at the expense of the original two crew members - was the core debate of the episode. It's only murder from one side of the debate, from the other it's simply correcting a mistake.

Comment: How excusable a murder is (in this case the needs of the many/two outway the needs of the one) does not erase its status as a murder.

Comment: @Omegacron There are a lot of definitions of the word murder, but let's use this one. "kill (someone) unlawfully & with premeditation." Was it lawful? Let's say this occurred in the alpha quadrant & Tuvix made an appeal to Starfleet or the United Federation of Planets. I highly doubt they would order him to die, even in this circumstance since he did nothing wrong & he is albeit created in an unorthodox way a sentient being w/rights. Clearly it was premeditated although I wouldn't argue that it would need to be to fit the definition of murder. Janeway took his life for her own selfish reasons.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, no.  As with many Voyager episodes, the events of *Tuvix* were not revisited in later episodes.

Both Tuvok and Neelix seemed to be aware that *something* had happened, but it wasn't discussed on-screen during the episode and it was never brought up again.

Given that there is no actual scientific basis for the event (nor any way a hybrid between two completely separate species from two wildly divergent evolutionary paths should be able to survive) we can't even speculate with any basis in facts.

We must therefore consider it from a storytelling perspective.  From that perspective, it is clear that Tuvok and Neelix both remembered all of Tuvix's memories (but probably not each other's memories that Tuvix didn't actively recollect and consider).  This is because it would heighten the drama and provide more storytelling possibilities - both Neelix and Tuvok would recall having been someone else, would have a connection to each other that was greatly expanded, and would potentially have different opinions as to if Janeway's actions were morally reprehensible or not.

As I said, though, that is purely speculation from the standpoint of storytelling needs/availability.  A definitive answer would have to come from Word of God, and even that may not be certain because the episode was freelanced, so the writer's opinions may differ from the studio's.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that the character of Tuvix is referenced again in either the novels or comics. The subject was a difficult one for the characters involved, so the topic of Tuvix or his memories is never brought up again on-screen. However, given the nature of the accident and the process used for separation, we have to assume that **neither Neelix nor Tuvok retained the memories of Tuvix**.

The Doctor ended up using a radioactive isotope to isolate the DNA of the two men, thus allowing the transporter to separate them and *restore them to their previous state*. This would indicate that their last memory would be of beaming up to the Voyager. Obviously, since they arrived in sick bay instead of the transporter room, they would know something occurred... but not what.

Comment: I disagree. If it was possible to restore them to their original state (using the transport buffer memory, etc.) they would have done so immediately. When Tuvix is created his clothes are also a blend of Tuvok's uniform and Neelix's suit. When they are separated, Tuvix is wearing a gold security uniform and both Tuvok and Neelix reappear with copies of the uniform, not their original clothes. Based on that I would say that they did retain Tuvik's memories. Coincidentally, when Tuvok and Neelix first met Neelix asked if he could have a uniform just like Tuvok's!